# Enable endpoints for kube-controller-manager & kube-scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kube-state-metrics

I am new to the kubernetes world and I am currently stuck with figuring out how to enable endpoints for `kube-controller-manager` & `kube-scheduler`. In some future, I'll be using the helm `kube-prometheus-stack` to scrape those endpoints for metrics. However, for now what would be the right approach to set up those endpoints?

```
$  kubectl get ep  -n kube-system
NAME                                        ENDPOINTS                 AGE
kube-controller-manager                     <none>                    105d
kube-scheduler                              <none>                    105d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No need to create endpoints for `kube-controller-manage` and `kube-scheduler` because they use `hostNetwork` and uses ports `10257` and `10259` respectively.
- you can verify it checking the manifests "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/" and netstat -nltp or ss -nltp on masternode

```
ss -nltp | grep kube
LISTEN   0         128                127.0.0.1:10257            0.0.0.0:*       users:(("kube-controller",pid=50301,fd=7))
LISTEN   0         128                127.0.0.1:10259            0.0.0.0:*       users:(("kube-scheduler",pid=50400,fd=7))
```

- so they should be accessible over < masternodeip >:<10257/10259>